# How to import a sub-module into a package's __init__.py in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, package

Suppose I have the following program structure:

```
.
├── main.py
└── mypack
    ├── __init__.py
    └── mymod.py
```

In the `mypack` package, it's possible to import objects in (sub-)modules using the syntax: `from .mymod import f`

**`mypack/__init__.py`**:

```
from .mymod import f

print(f'Hello: __name__: {__name__}, __package__: {__package__}, __file__: {__file__}')
```

However, if I try to import the full (sub-)module, I get the following syntax error:

```
import .mymod
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mypack
  File "/Users/nlykkei/python-demo/mypack/__init__.py", line 1
    import .mymod
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also, if I try to import the module using non-relative syntax, it fails:

```
import mymod

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mypack
  File "/Users/nlykkei/python-demo/mypack/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mymod
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymod'
```

How can I import a (sub-)module into the a package's `__init__.py` file? In particular, I want to import **only** the module object and **not** all its contained objects: `from .mymod import *`.

**Program output**:

```
$ python3 main.py
Hello: __name__: mypack.mymod, __package__: mypack, __file__: /python-demo/mypack/mymod.py
Hello: __name__: mypack, __package__: mypack, __file__: /python-demo/mypack/__init__.py
Hello: __name__: __main__, __package__: None, __file__: main.py
```

Comment: Have you tried just `from mymod import f`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understood the question, but maybe:

```py
from . import mymod
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your `__init__.py` file

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mypack
  File "/Users/nlykkei/python-demo/mypack/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mymod
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymod'
```

state you did not import `.mymod` but `mymod`

Comment: You are not reading my question fully then. That was only to show other things I've tried.

Comment: In the `__init__` you are declaring what your module content is (what you want to expose), so it is normal you cannot do `import mymod` . You need to explicitly state what you want to import / export from the module file `.mymod` , you can state `*` or list all function,objects you want to expose

Comment: What if I wanted to expose the (sub-)module object itself? E.g. `import mynod as foo`? A module is also an object, so it should be exposable.

Comment: In `__init__.py` from folder mypack/ the module you are defining is mypack.

Comment: Yes, and `mymod.py` is a sub-module.